# Accessing a single mediaplayer instance from multiple pages of a viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer, floating-action-button

I am trying to access a single mediaplayer instance from every ViewPager page. But every page create their own mediaplayer. How can i solve this?

I have declared a public Mediaplayer object on main activity.

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

and send its reference to ViewPagerAdapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Many code lines
viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this,0,data,mediaPlayer);
}
```

In viewpager adapter i pass the mediaplayer reference again where each page is created

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    page pg= new page(mediaPlayer);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("array",data.get(position));
    bundle.putString("title",mData[position]);
    pg.setArguments(bundle);
    return pg;
}
```

Then on everypage i have a recycler view so i created a adapter for it and pass the mediaplayer instance again

```
recyclerViewAdapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(this.getContext(),data,mediaPlayer);
```

Now on every page there are several buttons. every button play a different music

```
   holder.btn_clk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                mediaPlayer.release();
                Log.e("MP","Released.");
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("MP","Released Error.");
            }

            mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(mContext, file);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Everything is working fine except mediaplayer reference.

It seems like every page have created their own media player instance. If I press 2 different buttons on same page only latest music is playing. But if I press 2 different buttons form 2 different page both music are playing.

My main goal is to add a universal floating action button which will act as a stop button for every mediaplayer instance.
So i add one on mainactivity layout where viewpager is also located.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange_500"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_music_off_24"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(mContext, file);
```

You are creating a new player instance instead of using the existing one.

This definition should happen in your main activity.
Using context only may be.
and setting the file for each page.

You should use this constructor instead

```
Uri myUri = ....; 
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
    .build());
```

Then, you can update the content like this

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Then how can i play new music? i mean how can i change the file url for media player?

Comment: Use the other constructor, I updated the answer above.

Comment: which constructor?

Comment: Now i am creating mediaplayer on main activity

      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build());

Comment: and on each button click i am using 
  try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: I am getting 

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xoxo.xoxoxo, PID: 16090
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1243)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1210)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1102)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new class

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;

public class MP {
    public static MediaPlayer mp;

public static void stop(){
    if (mp != null){
        mp.stop();
    }
}

    public static void Play(View view, Uri file){
        if (mp != null)
            mp.reset();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), file);
        mp = mediaPlayer;
        try{
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```